# Inject model value into URL with Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to inject the value of a property into part of a URL to give it a unique filename:

```
<img src="/Content/img/portfolio/@item.Id.jpg">
```

This doesn't work as the dot after 'Id' obviously thinks it is expecting a property of itself. I've tried adding a space between Id and the .jpg but that gives me something like '123 .jpg'.

How can I inject the value?

Comment: Tag your questions correctly so-that it reaches correct audience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap `item.Id` in parantehesis

```
<img src="/Content/img/portfolio/@(item.Id).jpg">
```

### OR

```
<img src='@string.Format("/Content/img/portfolio/{0}.jpg", item.Id)'>
```