# How to have razor syntax inside of an image src tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a list of images in the application and there is a list of centers that each have images that are attached to those specific centers. I am trying to pull the specific image to the specific center in a foreach loop and I need to set the variable to the image number.

```
@foreach (var i in Model.GalleryImageMediaIds)
         {
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4 @active">`enter code here`
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" 
                src="/images/Center/Home/GalleryCardImages/@i.jpg" alt="slide 1">
            </div>
        }
```

I am trying to set i to the image number in the source but how do I have razor represent the number of that image? So if the image according to the center is 42 then the i will display 42. The @i does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inject model value into URL with Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164902/inject-model-value-into-url-with-razor)

Comment: what is the type of `GalleryImageMediaIds` ?

Comment: If are you using bootstrap, you can [do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59469712/4654957): https://stackoverflow.com/a/59469712/4654957

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the C# variable in explicit code block (`@(` and `)`).

```
<img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" 
                src="/images/Center/Home/GalleryCardImages/@(i).jpg" alt="slide 1" />
```

Assuming `i` is an int value which has a corresponding image in the specifid location *(ex :`/images/Center/Home/GalleryCardImages/1.jpg`)*